# Which Cookies for Azure AD B2C

Tags: session, cookies, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the following Microsoft sample web application. ■URL: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 (In the 1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C/ folder in the sample folder, using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet.csproj)

■ Procedure:

Launch this web application and sign in with my Azure AD B2C account.
check the session in the developer mode of the Edge browser.
The cookie in the below will be displayed.

```
ai_session
.AspNetCore.Cookies
ARRAffinitySameSite
ai_user
ARRAffinity
```

[Cookies when I login this site on POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G30aj.png)

■Question： Of these cookies, is ".AspNetCore.Cookies" cookie to be associated with the token issued by Azure AD B2C?

If not, which one is the "Cookie that is associated with the token issued by Azure AD B2C"?

I got Cookies that receiced when I signin, but I'm not sure which is associated with the token issued by Azure AD B2C.

I need to know it to make Cookie secured.

Answer (score 1):

> is ".AspNetCore.Cookies" cookie to be associated with the token issued by Azure AD B2C?

If you've configured your OpenID Connect settings to have `SaveTokens = true` then yes, this cookie will contain the tokens.

If you haven't then it will just contain the information ASP.NET Core needs to reconstruct a claims principal on each call.

> I need to know it to make Cookie secured.

If you're using ASP.NET Core and B2C then you should be using Microsoft.Identity.Web to interact with B2C and that includes cookie handling, which doesn't require you to know the name of the cookie to secure it:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(opt =>
        {
            this.configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", opt);
        },
        opt =>
        {
            opt.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

Even then, if you don't configure the cookie settings, by default the cookies will be configured as HttpOnly and Secure.